# iOS UITesting element appear few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

How can i assert that my spinner exists for a limited period of time?
I tried both exists and waitForExistence but since the element after few seconds disappear the test fails. If i remove from code stopAnimating (where the activityIndicatorView goes hidden) it just works.

```
func testShowsSpinnerOnLoad() {
    let spinner = app.activityIndicators.element(boundBy: 0)
    XCTAssertTrue(spinner.exists)
    XCTAssertTrue(spinner.waitForExistence(timeout: 3))
}
```

Comment: How long is your spinner on screen? It takes about a second or two to process the state of the app, depending on your computer's power, so if the spinner shows for less than a second, it will be very difficult to test with a UI test.

Comment: Yes thats the problem, the app launches, stays idle for 3 seconds where the spinner has already gone

Comment: If the spinner is part of the launch sequence, you will not be able to UI test it as the app is unavailable for querying until it has finished launching.